# Using two tablets as monitors with a mac

Tags: ipad, display, android

I want to use an Android tablet and an iPad as monitors with a Mac at the same time (greedy I know). Has anyone got this working?

Duet only seems to support one monitor. I don't know about Yam, but it's iPad only.

I'm trying to use both Duet and Yam at the moment, but getting issues with Duet connecting from Android (though it was working this morning). I'm not quite sure if this is an issue with Duet or if they don't play well together.

Answer (score 1):

So I seemed to be able to get this working.

The approach I used was to have Duet display on one tablet and Yam monitor on another tablet. I then set up the Duet monitor first (before connecting the Yam tablet - or starting Yam) and then setting up the Yam tablet. It looks like Duet doesn't like running while Yam is running ... I think.